# Do calls and puts have the same strikes?

Tags: options

This question may seem basic but it is not. It concerns about the details of the market structure. So please do not rush to close it. Consider the (liquid) options on a very liquid underlying, say the SPX option. Do the calls and puts all have the same strikes? If that is not generally true, what about the strikes close to the forward?

Comment: The Exchange decides what strikes and maturities will be traded. Of course at any available strike you can trade either puts or calls (and BTW their prices are related via the PCP so in some sense it is one market), but the meaning of your question is not clear to me. What is your concern, which is more liquid (the call or the put) ? And why in the final part you refer to the forward price? Please give some background for your question.

Comment: Generally at any strike the out of the money choice (put or call) will have more activity than the ITM, where ITM/OTM can judged using the forward (ITMF/OTMF). But either one can be traded.